# dataframe - Check condition on a number column and modify column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe is like below:

```
NameA   401016815
NameB   
NameC   414969141
NameD   0403 612 699
```

How do I get dataframe to do a condition check [ first character is 4 and character length of number is 9 digits] and add a zero at start if the condition is met.

Condition check to see if character length in 12 digits but only contains 9 numbers, the space in between should be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`Series.str.len`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) to check the length of the string. [`Series.startswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) 
to check the beginning of the string. [`Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) to remove blanks. We use [`Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) 
to replace or add characters in specific positions:

```
#df=df.reset_index() #if Names is the index
df['Number'].mask(df['Number'].str.len()>=12,df['Number'].str.replace(' ',''),inplace=True)
start=df['Number'].str.startswith('4').fillna(False)
df['Number'].mask(start,'0'+df['Number'],inplace=True)
print(df)
```

---

**Output**

```
   Names      Number
0  NameA  0401016815
1  NameB         NaN
2  NameC  0414969141
3  NameD  0403612699
```

Comment: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str . I have type casted the vaklye to str, but the output column shows as blank.   `old['test'] = old['Mobile'].mask(start,'0'+ str(old['Mobile']),inplace=True)`

Comment: the problem is that it seems that your column has integer values, You could use: `old['Mobile']=old['Mobile'].astype(str)` 
previously

Comment: awesome how do I get rid of the nan?

Comment: if you want it to appear blank:`old['Mobile']=old['Mobile'].fillna('')`. if you want filter this row: `old[old['Mobile'].notna()]`. Please consider accept or upvote my answer:)